# How to set Parent Form WindowState property from Child Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms for my C# application. The main form has its *ControlBox* set to false and then creates the second form like so:

```
this.ControlBox = false;
new Form2().Show();
```

The second form is able to minimize and maximize. I need the main form *WindowState* property to be able to be set from the child form when the window is *minimized* or returning to its *normal* state.

The problem I am having is that the program crashes when I try to minimize the child window.

This is my code:

```
private void Form2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
        this.Parent.WindowState = this.WindowState;
}
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that `Form2` `Parent` property is null, calling `Show()` method doesn't actually set the `Parent` property of the shown Form (check it in debugger). The simplest workaround would be to pass `Form1` (calling `Form`) reference through constructor of the `Form2` (called `Form`) and than use that reference to set the `WindowState` property. Something like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1 = frm;
        this.SizeChanged +=Form2_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void Form2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
            form1.WindowState = this.WindowState;
    }
}
```

And than in the code of the Form1 you could change to:

```
this.ControlBox = false;
Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
frm.Show();
```

Comment: it works until you build it in Visual Studio and run it on another computer.. it says unhandled exception

Comment: I doubt that the problem is in the code I proposed,maybe somewhere else...?

Comment: Got it working! I had to manually configure the event handler after the parent form had been set to _form1_.  So `this.SizeChanged += Form2_SizeChanged;` should be `this.SizeChanged += new System.EventHandler(Form2_SizeChanged);` Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Pass form 1 (`this`) to a public property in Form 2 and modify it on form 2

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.f1 = this;
f.Show();
// or: new Form2 { f1 = this }.Show();
```

Form 2:

```
public Form1 f1;
[...]
[Event:]
f1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: an NullReferenceException is caught when I try this